# Unity: Specify Dependency name during configuration

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have following snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IConnection, SerialPortConnection>("SerialConnection");
    container.RegisterType<IConnection, ParallelPortConnection>("ParallelConnection");
    container.RegisterType<Device>("ParallelDevice");
    container.RegisterType<Device>("SerialDevice");
}
```

I want to register type `Device` under two different names, so that depending on the name requested `Device` instance would be initialized with appropriate `Connection`. Following is one way to solve this, just for demonstration:

```
public class ParallelDevice : Device {
    public ParallelDevice([Dependency("ParallelConnection")] IConnection connection) : base(connection) {}
}
public class SerialDevice : Device {
    public SerialDevice([Dependency("ParallelConnection")] IConnection connection) : base(connection) {}
}

// and register with 
container.RegisterType<Device, ParallelDevice>("ParallelDevice");
container.RegisterType<Device, SerialDevice>("SerialDevice");
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something like:

```
container.RegisterType<Device>("ParallelDevice").UseDependencyNames("ParallelConnection");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IConnection, SerialConnection>("SerialConnection")
    .RegisterType<Device, SerialDevice>(new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IConnection>("SerialConnection")));
```

or like this:

```
container
    .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
    .ConfigureInjectionFor<ParallelDevice>(new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IConnection>("ParallelConnection")));
```

[This article](http://www.agileatwork.com/testing-unity-container-configuration/) has more examples as well as some extensions for Unity that allow you to write tests like this:

```
[Test]
public void Should_inject_named_instance_of_encryption_provider()
{
    var service = container.Resolve<MyService>();

    AssertNamedInstanceWasResolved<IEncryptionProvider>("MyEncryptionProvider");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should strive to keep your code free of DI Container-specifics. In this case, you can simply define your devices without referencing Unity at all. Here's the SerialDevice as an example, but the ParallelDevice class is entirely similar:

```
public class SerialDevice : Device
{
    public SerialDevice(IConnection connection)
        : base(connection) { }
}
```

You can configure your container like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IConnection, SerialPortConnection>("SerialConnection");
container.RegisterType<IConnection, ParallelPortConnection>("ParallelConnection");
container.RegisterType<Device, SerialDevice>("SerialDevice",
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IConnection>("SerialConnection")));
container.RegisterType<Device, ParallelDevice>("ParallelDevice",
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IConnection>("ParallelConnection")));
```

This will allow you to resolve both Device objects like this:

```
var serialDevice = container.Resolve<Device>("SerialDevice");
var parallelDevice = container.Resolve<Device>("ParallelDevice");
```